# where are my gnome user settings?

Tags: linux, gnome

I had a gnome session die on me in the middle of setting some display options.  Now, I get a blank screen when I log in with this particular user.  I tried removing all the .gnome and .gconf directories in my home directory, but that didn't fix it, what else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

If you already removed .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd, try also removing .metacity.
The issue may be in your xsession for this account rather than Gnome settings.  The session setting should be in .gnome2/session, so removing this should have fixed your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check the */var/log/Xorg.0.log* file for errors. Since the session died in the middle of setting display options, you should also check if there is any change to *xorg.conf*. If there's a backup version, try replacing that. Finally, you should mention how exactly you're starting up the gnome session.

As for the gnome session directories, I think you've already removed the ones that matter. The GNOME Project has the [full list of hidden directories that the GNOME Desktop adds to the home directories of users](http://library.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/appendixa-0.html.en).